# Apply email retention policy to Inbox but not subfolders?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email

Our official email policy states that email older than 90 days in the Inbox is moved to Deleted Items, not including subfolders of the Inbox.  This wasn't a problem to implement in Exchange 2003.  In 2010, however, it appears that Policy Tags applied to the Inbox also apply to its subfolders.  How can I prevent this from occuring?

EDIT:

Here is the output of `Get-RetentionPolicy`:

```
RunspaceId              : b6a05d43-3e56-4348-9d0e-2d2bf7e6c283
RetentionId             : 56417b54-af3b-4c14-bd3c-9dcf9bdd133e
RetentionPolicyTagLinks : {Junk E-mail - 7 Days, Deleted Items - 7 Days, Sent Items - 90 Days, Inbox - 90 Days}
AdminDisplayName        :
ExchangeVersion         : 1.0 (0.0.0.0)
Name                    : Default Company Policy
DistinguishedName       : CN=Default Company Policy,CN=Retention Policies Container,CN=Company,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
Identity                : Default Company Policy
Guid                    : 56417b54-af3b-4c14-bd3c-9dcf9bdd133e
ObjectCategory          : domain.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Mailbox-Recipient-Template
ObjectClass             : {top, msExchRecipientTemplate, msExchMailboxRecipientTemplate}
WhenChanged             : 2/8/2013 2:18:11 PM
WhenCreated             : 2/8/2013 2:11:18 PM
WhenChangedUTC          : 2/8/2013 10:18:11 PM
WhenCreatedUTC          : 2/8/2013 10:11:18 PM
OrganizationId          :
OriginatingServer       : server.domain.com
IsValid                 : True
```

Comment: Could you provide a sanitized output of: Get-RetentionPolicy [name_of_policy] | fl

Comment: Okay, this has been provided in the original post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of Frank Wang on Microsoft's social forums:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/1761ae96-8f4c-44b2-83a4-3ddb8f80201d

...it sounds like you need to create an additional retention policy tag that applies to "All other folders in the mailbox" and select the "Disable this tag" radio button, and add that to your existing policy.

Comment: It looks like he suggests users will need to apply this tag themselves.  Furthermore, as Personal tags are an Enterprise feature, this would require all users have an Enterprise CAL...  We might as well just ask users to move their folders out of their inbox to the root of their mail store.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's going to be possible, based on what I can find. Here's another person trying to achieve what you are (also answered by Frank Wang, FWIW) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy/thread/988d78a3-eb57-4c45-8c75-b6466c616512

Comment: Another "no" http://www.networksteve.com/exchange/topic.php/Excluding_Inbox_Subfolders_from_Retention_Policy_Purges_-_Horrib/?TopicId=21729&Posts=2